# Hide a div that is buried in multiple divs..jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do you hide the TOP div if there is no value in the innermost div?

For example if there is no Uppercase Text in the inner div.. I need to use the top div class and the innermost div that will wrap the text if there is any and check to see if that innermost div is empty or not and if it is then hide the parent div itself?

Using jQuery? Can anyone help please?

```html
<div class="philosophy-bubble">
    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15_label" style='display:none'>carephilosophy</div>
    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15__ControlWrapper_RichHtmlField" class="ms-rtestate-field" style="display:inline" aria-labelledby="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15_label">
        <div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer">
            <div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap">
                <span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">carephilosophy</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer">
                <span dir="none">       
                    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15_RichHtmlField">
                        <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctl15$RichHtmlField$hiddenDisplay" type="hidden" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15_RichHtmlField_hiddenDisplay" value="?Providing caring and knowledgable philosophy medical care to patients" />
                        <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctl15$RichHtmlField$hiddenStorage" type="hidden" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15_RichHtmlField_hiddenStorage" value="?Providing caring and knowledgable philosophy medical care to patients" />
                        <DIV id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15_RichHtmlField_displayContent" class="ms-rtestate-write" EmptyPanelId="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15_RichHtmlField_EmptyHtmlPanel" style="display:;">PROVIDING CARING AND KNOWLEDGABLE MEDICAL CARE TO PATIENTS</DIV>
                        <DIV style="Clear:both;" class="ms-rteclear"></DIV>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is how sharepoint controls are rendered in browsers adding bunch of extra divs and spans..originally it was only the top div and the server control RichHtmlField where users can type in values and save during content entry...if that helps..

Answer (score 2):

To check if a div is empty you can do the following

```
if( $('.yourdivclass').is(':empty') )
{
  // your code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean hide the `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15_RichHtmlField` div when `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctl15_RichHtmlField_displayContent` is empty then you can use the class name of the inner div, with jQuery it's as simple as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ms-rtestate-write").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().length == 0) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have to hide the top level div 'philosopy bubble' because it is a styled div made to look like a speech bubble and if there is no content in the bubble its gonna be a funny looking empty bubble which needs to go away..please help..!!

Comment: @AJSwift so just change `$(this).parent().hide();` to: `$(this).parents(".philosophy-bubble").hide();`